# Wifi option is not showing in my Dual booted HP laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.1 and Windows 11

Tags: 20.04, wireless, lts

I updated my Windows 10 installation to Windows 11 on my HP laptop 10th Gen.

Earlier I had dual booted Windows 10, and Ubuntu 20.04.1, But after I upgraded to Windows 11, my Ubuntu WIFI drivers started to malfunction in ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Disable Fast Startup in Windows and shutdown prior to booting Ubuntu.

Comment: Any windows driver neither shows or works in Ubuntu I think you also have wrong Ubuntu version in both the title and question.